# Function must return true if thread fails

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, return-value

I have a function that does some work and if it failed or if there is an exception it returns true.
Now I am creating a thread in this function that is responsible for doing the same work. Now how can I make function return true if some exception is thrown while thread is executing this task?

```
   boolean read(){   
      service.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //does the required work.
      });
   }
```

Comment: Please tag the programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by providing the logic to be executed by a new thread in form of [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of `Runnable`. Unlike `Runnable`, `Callable` allows you to return some result to the code that invokes it in form of [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

```
boolean read() {   
   Future<Boolean> future = service.submit(() -> {
      // Do your calculations and return whatever is required
      return true;
   });

  // future.get() blocks current thread execution until Callable returns the result
  return future.get();
}
```

I would also recommend to read [ThreadPoolExecutor + Callable + Future Example](https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/threadpoolexecutor-callable-future-example/) article and JavaDocs for [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) classes.